# Integrate Application Insight with Service Fabric Stateless WebAPI

Tags: azure-service-fabric

How can we Integrate Application Insight with Service Fabric Stateless WebAPI?
Do we need to configure separate Listener for it?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a sample application for service fabric for full .NET Framework with Owin hosting. The sample include Dependency Injection and Application insight
https://github.com/duongthaiha/ServiceFarbricSampleApplication

Answer (score -1):

Add Nuget package: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native

Configure it:

```
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        // Adding Service Fabric Telemetry Initializer
        .ConfigureServices(services =>   services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer>((serviceProvider) => new FabricTelemetryInitializer()))
        // Configuring Applciation Insights
       .UseApplicationInsights()
       .Build();
        host.Run();
```

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-event-analysis-appinsights) [some](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/softwaresimian/2017/06/16/azure-service-fabric-application-insights-working-sample/) more [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric) for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.... But to be specific I am using Stateless WebAPI ,however I was able to configure it and it is working fine!!!.